# Chrome display issue with input tag

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following code:

```css
.searchdiv {
  width: 140px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #707070;
}
.searchbox {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  border-color: #121212;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
}
.searchbox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.maglass {
  position: fixed;
  top: 57px;
  left: 125px;
}
.maglass:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchdiv">
  <form action="/search.njs" method="GET">
    <input class="searchbox" type="text" name="query" value="" />
    <input class="maglass" type="image" src="/res/maglass.png">
    </img>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I run this, It outputs as:

[image: Search]

I would like to know what causes the black border, since none of the colors I specified include it.

I tried removing the `border-color` property, but that causes the entire border to be grey.

Comment: I am not sure that i understand problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mz0aq1y3/1/  Isolated, your code works fine (there is no black border, i see gray border)?

Comment: @nevermind, there is a part of black border on left & top side.

Comment: Really don't see it: http://jsfiddle.net/mz0aq1y3/2/ (white background), newest chrome, win7... don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does the black(ish) border show up on Chrome?**

The issue is because of the default UA settings in Chrome for the `input` box. The value is by default set to `inset` (can be seen from the Developer Console) and this is the one that seems to be causing the blackish (it is not black, it seems to be a semi-transparent black) inset border on the element.

[image]

The problem is more apparent to see when the border and background colors are changed. I have set some high contrast colors in the below snippet to visualize it.

```css
.searchdiv {
  width: 140px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #707070;
}
.searchbox {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  border-color: #121212;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
}
.searchbox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.maglass {
  position: fixed;
  top: 57px;
  left: 125px;
}
.maglass:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/* Just for demo */

.searchbox.contrast {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-color: yellow;
}
.searchdiv {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchdiv">
  <form action="/search.njs" method="GET">
    <input class="searchbox" type="text" name="query" value="" />
    <input class="maglass" type="image" src="/res/maglass.png">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="searchdiv">
  <form action="/search.njs" method="GET">
    <input class="searchbox contrast" type="text" name="query" value="" />
    <input class="maglass" type="image" src="/res/maglass.png">
  </form>
</div>
```

---

**What is the solution?**

The solution to this is very simple. Just override the default `border-style` and set it to `solid` like in the below snippet.

```css
.searchdiv {
  width: 140px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #707070;
}
.searchbox {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #121212;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
}
.searchbox:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.maglass {
  position: fixed;
  top: 57px;
  left: 125px;
}
.maglass:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/* Just for demo */

.searchbox.contrast {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-color: yellow;
}
.searchdiv {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchdiv">
  <form action="/search.njs" method="GET">
    <input class="searchbox" type="text" name="query" value="" />
    <input class="maglass" type="image" src="/res/maglass.png">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="searchdiv">
  <form action="/search.njs" method="GET">
    <input class="searchbox contrast" type="text" name="query" value="" />
    <input class="maglass" type="image" src="/res/maglass.png">
  </form>
</div>
```

[image]